# Cumulative portfolio summary

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mysql. All dates are in yyyy-mm-dd. This question will be clear if someone has knowledge of mutual funds.

1. NAVMaster - Stores the NAV of the schemes. NAV changes everyday, except holidays and weekends.

```
    +------------+--------------+-------+  
    | schemecode |   navdate    |  nav  |  
    +------------+--------------+-------+  
    |          1 |   2020-01-01 |    10 |  
    |          2 |   2020-01-01 |    10 |  
    |          3 |   2020-01-01 |    10 |  
    |          1 |   2020-01-02 |    11 |  
    |          2 |   2020-01-02 |    11 |  
    |          3 |   2020-01-02 |    11 |  
    |          1 |   2020-01-06 |    25 |  
    |          2 |   2020-01-06 |    25 |  
    |          3 |   2020-01-06 |    25 |  
    +------------+--------------+-------+  

insert into navmaster(schemecode,navdate,nav) values 
(1,'2020-01-01', 10),  
(2,'2020-01-01', 10),  
(3,'2020-01-01', 10),  
(1,'2020-01-02', 11),  
(2,'2020-01-02', 11),  
(3,'2020-01-02', 11),  
(1,'2020-01-06', 25),  
(2,'2020-01-06', 25),  
(3,'2020-01-06', 25)
```

2. Transactions - Stores the transactions done by a user. When a user buys a scheme with amount in purchamount. He will be allotted the units based on the transaction days's NAV (Purchamount/nav=units)

```
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  
| trdate     | schemecode |     purchamount | nav | units |  
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  
| 2020-01-01 |     2      |     1000        | 10  | 100   |  
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  
| 2020-01-01 |     1      |     1000        | 10  | 100   |  
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  
| 2020-01-02 |     1      |     1100        | 11  | 100   |  
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  
| 2020-01-02 |     2      |     880         | 11  | 80    |  
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  
| 2020-01-06 |     3      |     2000        | 25  | 80    |  
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  
| 2020-01-06 |     1      |     1000        | 25  | 40    |  
+------------+------------+-----------------+-----+-------+  


insert into transactions(trdate,schemecode purchamount,nav, units)  
('2020-01-01',2,1000,10,100),  
('2020-01-01',1,1000,10,100),  
('2020-01-02',1,1100,11,100),  
('2020-01-02',2, 880,11,80),  
('2020-01-06',3,2000,25,80),  
('2020-01-06',1,1000,25,40)
```

I need to show how the change in user's investment everyday. Value is calculated on the (cumulative unit balance)*(nav on that day).

Example:

1. On 2020-01-01 the user has invested 1000 in scheme 2 and 1000 in
   scheme 1. He got 100 units in each scheme. The invested amount is
   2000 and the value is 2000 on 2020-01-01.
2. On 2020-01-02, the user has invested 1100 in scheme1 and 880 in
   scheme 2. He got 100 units in scheme1 and 80 units in scheme2. The
   invested amount is 3980 and the value is 4180 (sch1 units-200*11) +
   (sch2 units- 180*11)
3. 2020-01-03, 2020-01-04, 2020-01-05 are holidays. So no NAV will be
   calculated. The previous days', that is 2020-01-02 value is shown on
   these holidays.
4. On 2020-01-06, the user has invested 2000 in scheme3 and 1000 in
   scheme 1. He got 80 units in scheme3 and 40 units in scheme1. The
   invested amount is 6980 and the value is 12500 (sch1 units-240*25
   +sch2 units-180*25 +sch3 units-80*25)

```
+----------------------+-----------+  
|  date  | invested  | value  |  
+----------------------+-----------+--------+  
| 2020-01-01  |  2000  |  2000  |  
| 2020-01-02  |  3980  |  4180  |  
| 2020-01-03(Holiday) | 3980  |  4180  |  
| 2020-01-04(Holiday)  |  3980  |  4180  |  
| 2020-01-05(Holiday)  |  3980  |  4180  |  
| 2020-01-06  |  6980  | 12500  |  
+----------------------+-----------+--------+
```

## I have reached here:

```
select a.navdate, sum(b.units) as cumulative_sales
from navmaster a join transactions b on a.navdate >= b.trdate and a.schemecode=b.schemecode
group by a.navdate order by a.navdate
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please format your post strings. It's too hard to recognize. :)

Comment: In general, the best way to get an answer on this forum is to post the following: (1) What data you have; (2) what data you want; (3) what you have tried.

So how should you present the data? Best thing to do is make a fiddle so we can edit it (consider http://sqlfiddle.com/) Next best is to post SQL commands so we can recreate the data on a local machine. After that, try to post in neat tables so we can cut and paste.

Comment: Also, it is very hard to figure out what the calculation is supposed to be. Can you explain it in words?

Comment: I am so sorry, I can't format the question properly.

Comment: I have made a fiddle for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b70cd/2

Comment: Thank you. I also need to calculate the value along with cumulative units. This value must also be calculated for the days in between like holidays.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your data. Firstly, I don't think you need the navmaster table, because the nav is available in the transactions table. Second, I'm not getting the same numbers as you are. For 1/1, I get 2000; For 1/2, I get 3980; There are only 3000 more units on 1/6, so I get 6980. Am I missing something? See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b70cd/8

Comment: Also, I don't know how to compute the value. On 1/1, it's just the purchamount; On 1/2, is purchamount+200.

Comment: I made some changes in the question explaining the concept.

Comment: In each case, what is the PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have. I think it gets closer to what you want, but it does not give the same answer as what you have. How do you know the nav for 1/6 for scheme 2?

```
select
   trdate,
   invested,
   sum(holding) value 
from
   (
      select
         trdate,
         (
            select
               sum(purchamount) 
            from
               transactions 
            where
               trdate <= t2.trdate
         )
         invested,
         schemecode,
         (
            select
               nav 
            from
               transactions 
            where
               trdate = t2.trdate 
               and schemecode = t2.schemecode
         )
         * (
         select
            sum(units) 
         from
            transactions 
         where
            trdate <= t2.trdate 
            and schemecode = t2.schemecode) holding 
         from
            transactions t2 
   )
   t1 
group by
   trdate
```

results in

```
trdate                  invested    value
2020-01-01T00:00:00Z    2000        2000
2020-01-02T00:00:00Z    3980        4180
2020-01-06T00:00:00Z    6980        8000
```

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. Can you mark the answer as correct for future users?